# ng-list not refreshed after adding an item in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm creating one of my first Ionic applications, this application is used to keep track of people you owe money to. I've created a page where you can add amounts, after adding an amount an ng-list is shown containing those amounts.

The problem is that, after adding an item to the array (name = amounts) that is used by ng-repeat to populate the list, it will not show that an item has been added until I refresh the page.

The code:

My html page that shows an overview of the amounts:

```
<ion-view style="" class=" " id="page2" title="Te ontvangen default page">
<ion-pane>
    <ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">
        <div style="margin-right:-20px;">
            <button ng-click="voegtoe()" class=" button button-balanced  button-full " style="left:-10px;" id="teOntvangenDefaultPage-button5">Toevoegen</button>
        </div>
        <ion-list class=" " id="teOntvangenDefaultPage-list1">
            <ion-item ng-repeat="amount in amounts">{{amount.naam}} {{amount.bedrag}} {{amount.datum}}
                <ion-option-button class="button-assertive"
                                 ng-click="delete(amount)">
                Delete
              </ion-option-button>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-pane>
</ion-view>
```

My html page for the add amount popup:

```
<ion-view style="" class=" " id="page5" title="Voeg toe">
<ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">
    <form class="list " id="voegToeOntvangenForm" name="voegToeOntvangenForm" ng-controller="voegToeOntvangenCtrl">
        <ion-list class=" " id="voegToe-list3">
            <label id="voegToeNaam" class="item item-input ">
                <span class="input-label">Naam</span>
                <input placeholder="Wie?" type="text" ng-model="naam">
            </label>
            <label id="voegToeBedrag" class="item item-input ">
                <span class="input-label">€</span>
                <input placeholder="Bedrag" type="number" ng-model="bedrag">
            </label>
            <label id="voegToeDatum" class="item item-input ">
                <span class="input-label">Datum geleend</span>
                <input placeholder="Datum geleend" type="date" ng-model="datum">
            </label>
        </ion-list>
        <button ng-click="saveOntvangen()" class=" button button-balanced  button-block " id="voegToe-button6">Toevoegen</button>
        <button ng-click="cancelOntvangen()" class=" button button-assertive  button-block " id="voegToeCancel-button6">Annuleren</button>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

My app.js file containing all controllers:

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
//- the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives']);


app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})


app.controller("OntvangenCtrl", function($scope, $location) {

    if(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records')) == null)
        {
            amounts = [];
        }
        else
        {
            amounts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records'));
        }


    console.log('ontvangenctrl');
    $scope.amounts = amounts;


    $scope.voegtoe = function() {

    $location.path("/toevoegenontvangen");
    }

    $scope.delete = function(item){


        var searchTerm = item;
        var records = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records'));

        for (var i=records.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

            if (angular.toJson(records[i]) === angular.toJson(searchTerm)) {

                records.splice(i, 1);
                // break;       //<-- Uncomment  if only the first term has to be removed
            }
        }

        window.localStorage.setItem('records', JSON.stringify(records));
        $scope.amounts = records;

        }

    $scope.deleteall = function(){

        var records = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records'));

        for (var i=records.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                records.splice(i, 1);
        }

        window.localStorage.setItem('records', JSON.stringify(records));

        }

});

app.controller("voegToeOntvangenCtrl", function($scope, $location, $window) {

    $scope.saveOntvangen = function() {

        //console.log($scope.naam);
        //console.log($scope.bedrag);
        //console.log($scope.datum);
        var amounts;

        if(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records')) == null)
        {
            amounts = [];
        }
        else
        {
            amounts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records'));
        }

        var current = new Object();
        current.naam = $scope.naam;
        current.bedrag = $scope.bedrag;
        current.datum = $scope.datum;

        amounts.push(current);

        console.log(amounts);

        window.localStorage.setItem('records', JSON.stringify(amounts));

        $scope.amounts = amounts;

        $window.location.href = "#/teontvangen/teontvangen";

}

$scope.cancelOntvangen = function() {

        $location.path("/teontvangen");


}



});

app.controller("voegToeBetalenCtrl", function($scope, $location) {



});
```

my routes.js file:

```
angular.module('app.routes', [])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider



      .state('tabsController.teOntvangenDefaultPage', {
    url: '/teontvangen',
    views: {
      'tab1': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/teOntvangenDefaultPage.html',
        controller: 'OntvangenCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tabsController.teBetalenDefaultPage', {
    url: '/tebetalen',
    views: {
      'tab2': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/teBetalenDefaultPage.html',
        controller: 'teBetalenDefaultPageCtrl'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tabsController', {
    url: '/teontvangen',
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabsController.html',
    abstract:true
  })

  .state('voegToe', {
    url: '/toevoegenontvangen',
    templateUrl: 'views/voegToeOntvangen.html',
    controller: 'voegToeOntvangenCtrl'
  })

  .state('voegToe2', {
    url: '/toevoegenbetalen',
    templateUrl: 'views/voegToeBetalen.html',
    controller: 'voegToeBetalenCtrl'
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/teontvangen/teontvangen')



});
```

Is there anyone who has an idea why this is happing?

Comment: use scope.$apply(); in controller

Comment: in $scope.saveOntvangen function, after $window.location.href = "#/teontvangen/teontvangen"; ?

Comment: updated answer check it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `$scope.$apply()` or`$scope.$applyAsync();`, after your data binding.

Here are the docs on it: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
//- the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.services' is found in services.js
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives']);


app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})


app.controller("OntvangenCtrl", function($scope, $location) {

    if(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records')) == null)
        {
            amounts = [];
        }
        else
        {
            amounts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records'));
        }


    console.log('ontvangenctrl');
    $scope.amounts = amounts;
    $scope.$applyAsync();

    $scope.voegtoe = function() {

    $location.path("/toevoegenontvangen");
    }

    $scope.delete = function(item){


        var searchTerm = item;
        var records = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records'));

        for (var i=records.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

            if (angular.toJson(records[i]) === angular.toJson(searchTerm)) {

                records.splice(i, 1);
                // break;       //<-- Uncomment  if only the first term has to be removed
            }
        }

        window.localStorage.setItem('records', JSON.stringify(records));
        $scope.amounts = records;
        $scope.$applyAsync();
        }

    $scope.deleteall = function(){

        var records = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records'));

        for (var i=records.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
                records.splice(i, 1);
        }

        window.localStorage.setItem('records', JSON.stringify(records));

        }

});

app.controller("voegToeOntvangenCtrl", function($scope, $location, $window) {

    $scope.saveOntvangen = function() {

        //console.log($scope.naam);
        //console.log($scope.bedrag);
        //console.log($scope.datum);
        var amounts;

        if(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records')) == null)
        {
            amounts = [];
        }
        else
        {
            amounts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records'));
        }

        var current = new Object();
        current.naam = $scope.naam;
        current.bedrag = $scope.bedrag;
        current.datum = $scope.datum;

        amounts.push(current);

        console.log(amounts);

        window.localStorage.setItem('records', JSON.stringify(amounts));

        $scope.amounts = amounts;
        $scope.$applyAsync();
        $window.location.href = "#/teontvangen/teontvangen";

}

$scope.cancelOntvangen = function() {

        $location.path("/teontvangen");


}



});

app.controller("voegToeBetalenCtrl", function($scope, $location) {



});
```

Comment: I've tried this before, but I'm getting this error: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: updated my answer with $scope.$applyAsync(); function

Comment: Thanks for putting your time into this, the error is gone now but it still isn't working until after I manually refresh by pressing f5.

Answer (score 0):

use $timeout and add call your function it will call $apply automatically and the values will be also refreshed.

Comment: Can you explain why you would do this, and where in the code I need to implement this? I'm new to angularjs :).

Comment: ng-click="saveOntvangen()" class=" button button-assertive instead of this use ng-click="$timeout(saveOntvangen,500);

Comment: I've tried this, but the values still don't show up until after the refresh. Any further ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

In voegToeOntvangenCtrl controller you are using this

```
var amounts;

    if(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records')) == null)
    {
        amounts = [];
    }
    else
    {
        amounts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records'));
    }
```

instead of this you should use amounts variable with $scope at everywhere you have used amounts

```
$scope.amounts=[];

    if(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records')) == null)
    {
        $scope.amounts = [];
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.amounts = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('records'));
    }
```

Hope this'll solve your problem